# How can I move my table on top of the page?

Tags: tables

How can I adjust my table on the top of the page?
I want to move slightly my table on top. Should I use some margin or padding command in order to that?

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3.7cm}{}
\begin{tabular}{|p{.6\textwidth}|p{.75\textwidth}|}
\hline
{\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,language={Java},
numbersep=8pt,numbers=left,xleftmargin=0.5cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords={class,run}]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}
class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread
    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
        x.thread.start(0);
        x.thread.join(0);
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}}
&
{\begin{lstlisting}[
basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
identifierstyle={\color{black}},
tabsize=2,
language={Java},
numbersep=8pt,
numbers=left,
xleftmargin=0.5cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=2pt,framerule=0pt,
morekeywords ={class,run}
]
class PrintHelloThread ext Thread {
    void run(Dummy x) {
        out.println("Hello world")
    }
}
class X ext ProxifiedObject {
    PrintHelloThread thread
    void main(X x) {
        x.thread := new PrintHelloThread;
        x.thread.start(0);
        x.thread.join(0);
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustwidth}
\caption{\label{fig:text}text experiment ent experiment experiment}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is at the top:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/ODg90.png  If you want it to go up further, you have to reduce the top margin.

Comment: You can move it by little if you use `aboveskip=0pt` for listings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examining my own post, I found out a way to move the table on top of the page.

The command ***vspace*** simply solves my problem.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-3cm}{}
\vspace{-7.5em}%
.....
\end{table}
```

Answer (score -4):

Or notice `[ht]` after `\begin{table}`. The `t` stands for top (`h` for here). 
So, if you only write `\begin{table}[t]`...and the rest...
the table should go to the top of the page.